# SSAS: Display of distinct Dimensional attribute values

Tags: ssas-2012

My issue is unable to displaying distinct dimensional attribute values in the filter expression using SSAS. I have this dimension that contains Key, Att_1 and the property value for Att_1 is set to collection ie. Att_1 and Key. (I am having to set this to collection for two reasons: 1. since the cube process ends in error 'duplicate rows found' and 2. Using SqlServerDataTools)

Answer (score 0):

This occurred due to the wrong setup of association of dimensional attributes and underlying data issue. Firstly, revisit and resetting to key, value and name values of Att_1 at leaf level. Secondly, collation was set at key, value and name to correct the duplication issue.